# Ordering/Reordering the list based on a specific column which holds an order number in JPA

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I'm using JPA and also I have a table like below structure:

```
|--------------|--------------------------------|
|      ID      |     Title    |   OrderNumber   |
|--------------|--------------|-----------------|
|      1       |      Test    |      0          |
|--------------|--------------|-----------------|
|      2       |      Test2   |      1          |
|--------------|--------------|-----------------|
```

So, It's easy to order the list by the 'OrderNumber' in queries, but I've not found an appropriate way to update/set its value in reordering operation yet (Because I have an option in user-side to change the order of the list by drag and drop).

What is a suitable way to solve this problem without any store procedure in the database?

Comment: I do not see any special thing here. You should just update the `OrderNumber` column by request from user-side.

Comment: @SternK so what would be happened for other OrderNumbers? I mean if I change the orderNumber of the first column to '1', what will be happened for another row with similar orderNumber, and what will be happened for other rows whose orderNumbers are higher or lower than its orderNumber?

Comment: If you change the `orderNumber` of the first row to '1' then other row should take the place of  0. All rows unrelated to this particular reordering  should not change the `orderNumber` value